# Install SCCM application to client via powershell, comand line or WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi, application, sccm-2012

I am trying to create a script in powershell that request and install an available application for a user or computer in the sccm application catalog.

I know that there is a way to force sccm client actions using wmi methods.

Example

```
WMIC /namespace:\\root\ccm path sms_client CALL TriggerSchedule "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003}" /NOINTERACTIVE
```

There is a way that by executing a wmi method or command line, in the users computer, to force the installation of and application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in vbscript if you're interested.  I'm not well versed in powershell yet but I do alot of .net and vbscript automation of SCCM.  I'm sure someone here could translate to powershell.

```
'Declare WMI connection to CCM, temporarily disable errors so the script doesnt stop if the namespace doesn't exist.  We will handle the error next.

On Error Resume Next
      Dim oWMI : Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\ccm\ClientSDK")
On Error Goto 0

' Check the datatype of oWMI to make sure its not null for error handling.

If VarType(oWMI) > 1 Then 

    'Run a query for all applications
    Dim colItems, objItem : Set colItems = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from CCM_Application")

    'Same as above... error handling in case nothing was returned
    If VarType(colItems) > 1 Then 

    ' Iterate through all the applications available
        For Each objItem in colItems
            Wscript.Echo "Application: " & objItem.FullName & vbCr & _ 
            "Description: " & objItem.Description & VbCr & _ 
            "Publisher: " & objItem.Publisher & VbCr & _ 
            "Version: " & objItem.SoftwareVersion & VbCr & _ 
            "Install State: " & objItem.InstallState & VbCr & _ 
            "Id: " & objItem.Id & VbCr & _ 
            "Revision: " & objItem.Revision

            'In my example, if the application is Adobe Air then run the install action

            If objItem.FullName = "Adobe Air" and ObjItem.InstallState = "NotInstalled" Then

                'First three parameters identify the application (id, revision, and ismachinetarget).  The Next 3 are EnforcePreference, Priority and IsRebootIfNeeded options.
                '0, "Foreground", "False" sets immediate foreground install with no reboot
                'See the msdn page for info about what other options you can set: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj902780.aspx

                Dim ReturnCode : ReturnCode = objItem.Install(objItem.Id, objItem.Revision, objItem.IsMachineTarget, 0, "Foreground", "False")

                'Returns 0 if it successfully started the install.  This does NOT return the exit code of the installation itself.

                Wscript.Echo "Return Code: " & ReturnCode

            End If
        Next

    End If

End If
```